# Dual polygons: terminology

Tags: geometry, polygons, duality-theorems

A question about terminology: is there a specific reason why, given a polygon $P$, the polygon $P^*$ constructed by connecting the midpoints of the edges of $P$ is called the 'dual polygon'? Thanks to anybody who might know, did not find anything on the internet, and perhaps it is just a convention.

Comment: in general, one uses 'dual' to refer to the image under an involutive map (i.e., a map that composed with itself gives the identity). Namely, the dual of the dual of an object should be the object itself. Here the 'duality' exchanges vertices with edges. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_polyhedron

Comment: It is not involutive in the sense that it gives you back the original shape or some rescaled version of it (any quadrilateral turns into a parallelogram and from that point on, you only get parallelograms by induction). I guess it is just freely used as a suggestive description of exchange of edges and vertices (which is not involutive either), since they seem to sort of reallign to the original ones once you apply it twice.

Comment: probably the terminology originates from 'projective duality': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)

Comment: It's a duality of the obvious poset associated to the polygon, which captures the combinatorial structure (but not the rigid geometric structure).

Comment: @Arthur "Here" the context is polygons, so duality exchanges vertices with edges, just as Giulio R said.  (In general it exchanges vertices with facets, i.e., top-dimensional faces.)

Comment: @JBL You're right. I was thinking polyhedra, for some reason. Like the platonic solids and such.

Comment: @GiulioR Thank you, I did not know of this notion, now it all makes sense!